# Protecting MAX485 data or supply from shorting to 24 V DC supply

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, protection, rs485

I have 2000 infrared proximity sensors along 100 meters, divided to 2 meter sections, with an Arduino reading them and sending results by MAX485.

For the power, I am supplying the same 24V DC from each end of the line to prevent voltage drop; I don't have much space for a big wire, so I had to do that.

In every 2 meter section there is a small switching buck reducing voltage to 5 V for the Arduino and other components, including the MAX485.

This is a design for an industrial purpose where EMF noise is present and the air is so humid and dusty, increasing the possibility of shorting on the PCB itself! I have already read other questions which were close to mine, but some points are still not clear to me:

1. In case of a short between 24 V and 5 V to the micro, what will happen? And how to prevent it?
2. What about a short between 24 V DC and RS485 data? How to prevent that?

For the first point, even if it happens, in the worst situation I will lose my components on one section, but for the second one I guess all 50 sections are in danger.

I will use TVS diodes like SM712 which is really designed for transients and RS485 voltage levels, but I guess it can not help me with the short circuit.

The 380 V AC to 24V DC power supply has enough protection, and also a circuit breaker will be provided for the whole 24 V line.

As I read in the same questions before, I will separate data and power cables, use earth connection, use different connectors for them, so the installation will be fool proof!

Answer (score 1):

1. The micro will surely be destroyed. You can prevent it by either preventing the short in the first place or by adding series or shunt protection. For example, you could add an LDO regulator on each board that is capable of withstanding 24 VDC on the input (series protection).
2. Most RS-485 protection schemes are designed to handle transients, not a direct short to something like 24 V so you would probably destroy a shunt protection device (typically a [TVS array](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/CDSOT23-SM712-1635169.pdf) is used); if you add a series polyfuse type PTC or [MOSFET based current limiter](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/TBU-CA-778169.pdf) you can make a short to +24 V survivable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a circuit(s) called active clamps. My favorite was to use a crowbar configuration where a SCR was gated on when the voltage exceeded the zener voltage + trigger voltage of the SCR. Once the SCR triggered it shorted the 5V and or 24V bus and tripped the circuit current protection device. Here is a circuit from [Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/Crowbar-Circuit/). SD1 is optional. You need to scale the parts to match your requirement.

[image: Crowbar circuit]

An active clamp will act like a shunt regulator and generate a lot of heat.

I am recommending the crowbar circuit because it is inexpensive, compact and parts are (were pre covid) easy to come by. This should protect each circuit and protect the expensive electronics.  Let us know how this works.